# Static invocation via $this on laravel model repository

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, repository

I inject laravel model via construct on repository pattern
But when i call some method using object operator `->` via $this my IDE display warning if it should be used `..::with(...)` instead.
So what is the best practice for calling this method using `::` or `->` ?

Here my example code

1. PostRepository.php using Object Operator

```
class PostRepository {
    private Post $model;
    
    public function __construct(Post $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
    
    public function getPost()
    {
        $query = $this->model->with('user');
    
        return $query->get();
    }
}
```

2. PostRepository.php using scope operator

```
class PostRepository {
    private Post $model;
    
    public function __construct(Post $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }
    
    public function getPost()
    {
        $query = $this->model::with('user');
    
        return $query->get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check the `Model` class and look for the `with` method you'll see it's a static method which is why your IDE is displaying a warning.

```
// Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
public static function with($relations){
    //...
}

// Must be called statically...
$this->model::with('user');
```

If you're passing in a `Post` model instance I'd probably pivot to using `load` or even `loadMissing` to fetch your relation:

```
$this->model->load('user');

// Or
$this->model->loadMissing('user');
```

The `loadMissing` method is useful because it'll only load that relation if it's not already been loaded, giving you the option to preload it before passing it in.

Comment: So i call this it like this `$this->model->load('user')->get()` ?
And how about if i want using another static method like `find` `newQuery` `query` `all` and other ?

Comment: Are you passing a `Post` model instance into your constructor?

Comment: Yup.. using laravel automatic injection https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/container#automatic-injection

Like on repository pattern tutorial mention it here => https://medium.com/employbl/use-the-repository-design-pattern-in-a-laravel-application-13f0b46a3dce

Comment: i just want to know what is the best practice for this because my IDE display a warning but the code still can run normally.

Comment: If you're starting a new query that includes `with` use the static declaration. If you just want to load the user into the instance you already have, use `load` or `loadMissing`